# How to remove rectangular box around text from sublime text editor

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I want to remove the crummy boxes around text show in:

[image]

I can't remember which package I had installed for this. Can anybody tell me how?

Comment: Possibly this can help you. [Link on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`control + shift + p` or `cmd + shift + p` and  type **package control:disable package** and then type `sublimelinter` and click.
if it doesn't work then type `anaconda` and click for disable

Answer (score 2):

These are All linter effects, goto **Preferences > Package Setting > anaconda > Settings-user** and **Add these lines**

```
{
    "anaconda_tooltip_theme": "tooltip",
    "anaconda_gutter_marks": true,
    "anaconda_gutter_theme": "none",
    "anaconda_linter_underlines": true,
    "python_interpreter": "python3",
    "anaconda_linting_behaviour": "save-only", // Don't Want to see these if you are writing
    "anaconda_linting": false //disable permanently
}
```